# Show that $\phi : H\to HN/N$ defined by $\phi(h)=hN$ is injective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I am trying to show the following:

> Show that $\phi : H\to HN/N$ defined by $\phi(h)=hN$ is injective.

Note that $H\leq G$ and $N$ is normal in $G$.

My attempt so far: Let $\phi(h_{1})=\phi(h_{2})$. Then $h_{1}N=h_{2}N$ or there exists an $n\in N$ such that $h_{1}=h_{2}n$.

This is where I am stuck. I apologize for my elementary knowledge in cosets and quotient groups. Can anyone point me to the right direction, such as a property for cosets, to help me?

Comment: If $H=N$ this is not injective... Am I missing something?

Comment: For "injective", read "surjective"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am not sure whether I am supposed to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism or an isomorphism. So $\phi$ is a hom. instead of an iso.?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown (sorry for the double reply) If $\phi$ is only a hom., then I just need to show well-defined and operation preserving then, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. $\phi$ is a homomorphism and you have $h\in Ker(\phi)$ $\iff$ $hN=N$ $\iff$ $h\in H\cap N$. So the kernel is trivial only when $H\cap N=\{e\}$.

Comment: Oh! So you're saying $\phi$ is supposed to be shown as a homomorphism and not an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, it's not an isomorphism. It is a surjective homomorphism and as $Ker(\phi)=H\cap N$ it gives a proof of the second isomorphism theorem which says $H/(H\cap N) \cong HN/N$.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for helping me; this makes things much more easier!